# ajax is not calling function, gives wrong response

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to make an ajax call in wordpress plugin, here is the code of constructor!

//actions

```
 add_action('init', array($this,'plugin_license_init'));
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_plicense_getlicense', 'plicense_ajax_getlicense');
    add_action('wp_ajax_plicense_getlicense', 'plicense_ajax_getlicense');

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript">

        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

//on button click event

        $("#regenerate_license").click(function() 
        {
                //$('.plic-loading-icon').show();
            // jquery.post has 3 parameter

            $.post( ajaxurl, {'action': "plicense_ajax_getlicense"}, function(response) 
                     {
                        alert(response);

                        $("#license_key").val(response);
                        //$('.plic-loading-icon').hide();
                     }
                 );
    });
});
        </script>
```

//the function I want to call

```
public function plicense_ajax_getlicense() 
    {

        global $plicense_settings;
        //$this->plicensing_generate_guid( );
        echo "hey";
    }
```

//when the button is clicked...the response I get is

```
<style>         .h{             width:98%;              height:4em;             border-style:solid ;................       {                        alert(response);                        $("#license_key").val(response);                        //$('.plic-loading-icon').hide();                     }                 );    });});        </script>       0
```

its the source code of the same html page

Comment: then what you want as ressponse?

Comment: i have a $this->plicensing_generate_guid( ); function which i commented above....instead it should send "hey" string...but it doesn't

Comment: Where is `ajaxurl` defined?

Comment: dont know! :P but it should use admin-ajax.php

Comment: Try hardcoding the desired path instead of using `ajaxurl`. If that works, then you need to figure out why `ajaxurl` does not have the intended value.

Comment: "but it should use admin-ajax.php"

Comment: i have used "admin-ajax.php" instead of ajaxurl, but i got the same long string in response

Comment: Why do your `wp_ajax_*` action hooks not pointing to a class method? - `add_action('wp_ajax_plicense_getlicense', array($this, 'plicense_ajax_getlicense'));` . . . . Also, do you have `WP_DEBUG` enabled?

Comment: yes...debug is enabled, i have replaced the action, but still the same result. and I dont know why it is not calling my class method

Answer (score 0):

You can remove one library from two jQuery libs:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script  src="http:.../libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
```

you can remove the second one.

Comment: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

here is the warning in the console

Answer (score 0):

Change your codd a bit
change the action function in your jQuery and this will solve the problem

```
$.post( ajaxurl, {'action': "plicense_getlicense"}, function(response) 
  {
         alert(response);
         $("#license_key").val(response);
         //$('.plic-loading-icon').hide();
   }
   );
```